# wordpress postgres database connection issue

Tags: php, wordpress, postgresql

I'm trying to use the pg4wp postgresql plugin for wordpress. I provide the host, user(with super user role) and password correctly. But I still get the following error.

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'wordpressuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/main-landing/blog/wp-content/pg4wp/core.php(32) : eval()'d code on line 1386
>
> Warning: error_log(/var/www/html/main-landing/blog//wp-content/pg4wp/logs/pg4wp_unmodified.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/main-landing/blog/wp-content/pg4wp/driver_pgsql.php on line 482
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/main-landing/blog/wp-content/pg4wp/driver_pgsql.php on line 274
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/main-landing/blog/wp-content/pg4wp/driver_pgsql.php on line 288
>
> Warning: error_log(/var/www/html/main-landing/blog//wp-content/pg4wp/logs/pg4wp_unmodified.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/main-landing/blog/wp-content/pg4wp/driver_pgsql.php on line 482
>
> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "session" LINE 1: SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode ^ in /var/www/html/main-landing/blog/wp-content/pg4wp/driver_pgsql.php on line 136

My pg_log throws the following error:

> ERROR:  relation "wp_options" does not exist at character 26
>       STATEMENT:  SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' LIMIT 1

Can't figure this out

Comment: It looks like something (a plugin, maybe) is sending MySQL-specific statements. `SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode` doesn't make sense in PostgreSQL, it's a MySQL extension.

Answer (score 0):

Put bluntly, don't even try to not use MySQL with WordPress. This plugin is merely one of many that have tried to make WP play well with Postgres. They all failed owing to lack of maintenance and plugin compatibility.

As you may have noted on the [plugin's page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postgresql-for-wordpress/), this one is no exception: it hasn't been updated for months in spite of how WP's core has evolved in recent versions, and it mentions the usual caveats with respect to plugins.

Comment: The problem is I already have postgres instance running on my server which is being used for the main application. Don't you think installing mysql instance just for a blog would take alot of resources.

Comment: It will take resources, but that is a non-issue in your case. Your options are basically a) use resources for MySQL to power your blog or b) have a broken blog today or at some point tomorrow. There are no other options. Pick one.